# When typing in input and if not email with @ and .com etc show error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making this login field that is supposed to be more automatic and not manual like normal fields. I'm trying to show errors while you type and enter your details, and not after you have pressed "submit" and checked if the details is correct.

For example if you have not typed @ or .com/.no/.co.uk in an email field: make error message automaticlly appear.

Or for example if you have typed only two letters and you need minium 6 letters: show error automaticlly appear.

Comment: and? what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide code, this website is for help, not for doing it for you.

Comment: `min-length` and `type="email"`

Comment: http://formvalidator.net/ -a good plugin for your problem

Comment: @Aaron formvalidator.net looks good.. but I want to show the message as soon as you type, not after you have clicked outside the box. Bootstrap (https://github.com/paulyoder/angular-bootstrap-show-errors) could also work, but it still wont show as soon as you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hard coded for you, there must some libraries doing this automatically for you, but you can start with here.

```
$('#inputName').keyup(function ()
{
     YOUR VALIDATION CODE
}
```

you only need keyup function which means on text change for input.

[HERE IS THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/29m5rrhh/)

Comment: Thanks! I used hide(); instead of text("");. Do you have any idea how to connect the fields with the submit button? Unlock sumbit button when all fields are correct from the validation code of the form.

Comment: @VemundEldegard I suggest you to show submit button always, think that there are many types of end users who can disabled javascript, so if an user disabled js how you gonna register that user without showing submit button. So I suggest show submit button always, and also do your validation in both backend and front end that's what I am doing